# Running Nunit Test in Administrator Mode

Tags: c#, nunit, administrator

I am currently using VS 2015 professional and using Nunit Framework for unit testing.

I am using the same framework for integration testing as well. While doing so I realized, one of the `.dll` supplied by the hardware manufacturer requires Administrator Privileges for it to be used in an application or tests(my current issue lies here) I did some research and tried a few things mentioned below to use the `dll` in admin mode.

**1** So I started the Visual Studio in Administrator mode for the test to run, but still the `dll` (functions) do not work. (running test in VS debug mode)

**2** I just used normal debug without Nunit framework, then the `dll` worked.

My conclusion --> I think that the Nunit somehow is not elevated to Admin.

Questions and Problem

I need to use the dll in Admin mode for the integration testing(where i use Nunit Framework)

1. Is it possible to do so?
2. If no, then why and if yes, then how

Please provide your input

Comment: anyone!! please help

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't said what "running nunit" means. We have about six different ways to run tests. :-) Please edit to say how you run your NUnit tests, i.e. nunit3-console, vs adapter, etc. The answer will vary accordingly.